# Pass child process output to terminal window, but also capture in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, child-process, stderr

I know that I can pass a child process's `stdout` and `stderr` through to the terminal by passing the option `{ stdio: 'inherit' }`, i.e.

```sh
child_process.spawnSync('echo', ['hello'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
```

And I know that I can *instead* capture it in a variable by omitting that option:

```sh
const child = child_process.spawnSync('echo', ['hello'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
const output = child.stdout.toString()
```

But what if I want to *both* let the output flow through to the terminal *and* capture the output in a variable? My current solution looks like this:

```sh
const child = spawn('echo', ['hello'])
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)

let stdout = ''
let stderr = ''

child.stdout.on('data', buffer => {
  stdout += buffer.toString()
})

child.stderr.on('data', buffer => {
  stderr += buffer.toString()
})

child.stdout.on('close', buffer => {
  console.log('captured stdout', stdout)
})

child.stderr.on('close', buffer => {
  console.log('captured stderr', stderr)
})
```

But the `pipe` approach doesn't work as perfectly as `{ stdio: inherit }`. If the command being run *updates* an existing line of stdout (imagine a progress % that is incrementing), I don't see that update happening in real time. I only see the end result.